# Prove that A is a subset of B. {...for some odd integer}

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

A={ $a$ ∈ Z | $a= b^2 $ for some odd integer b}

B={ $a$ ∈ Z| $a= 8k +1 $ for some k ∈ Z}

I am totally lost on where to start. Would I make b= 2m+1?

Comment: Making $b=2m+1$ is a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$b = 2k + 1$

$b^2 = (2k + 1)^2 = 4k^2 + 4k + 1 = 4(k^2 + k) + 1 =  4(k+1)k + 1$

Either $k +1 $ or $k$ is divisible by $2$, so $4(k+1)k = 8n$ for some $n$

so, $b^2 = 8n + 1$ if $b$ is odd. The opposite is not necessary true, e.g. 17 = 2*8 + 1 is not a full square.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the only cases in which $b^2$ is odd:

- $b\equiv1\pmod8 \implies b^2\equiv1^2\equiv 1\equiv1\pmod8$
- $b\equiv3\pmod8 \implies b^2\equiv3^2\equiv 9\equiv1\pmod8$
- $b\equiv5\pmod8 \implies b^2\equiv5^2\equiv25\equiv1\pmod8$
- $b\equiv7\pmod8 \implies b^2\equiv7^2\equiv49\equiv1\pmod8$